# Firefox form inputs/divs inside label behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, mootools

I am submitting a form via javascript as callback of a label click. It works on all browsers except Firefox, and I am currently testing on FF24.

This is the label structure:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="itsname" value="1">
    <div>
        <img />
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div><br></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</label>
```

And this is the (pseudo)code for submitting the parent form:

```
label.addEvent('click', function () {
    if(Browser.firefox) this.getChildren('input')[0].set('checked', true)
    this.getParents('form')[0].submit()
})
```

As you can see, the code is already fixed for FF, so I am not really looking for a solution but just for a more or less detailed explanation on why the additional code is mandatory for making the script work in FF. I already know the radio input gets checked "too late" otherwise.

Comment: The example is not valid HTML. labels should not contain divs. Also, if you add a `for` attribute to the label, does it work correctly?

Comment: You haven't explained what you are trying to achieve. Why do you only set the check state of the input in Firefox. Why not other browsers?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I already tried replacing block elements, but this did not affect its behavior. Also the `for` attribute seems not to be the cause.

Comment: @cbp My goal is to successfully submit the form with all the input data belonging to it. Other browsers do not need the check state to be enforced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is probably a race condition whereby the form `.submit()` hijacks the default label behavior and prevents it from bubbling to the input and changing its value.

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/mjLya/

```
var html = document.getElement('input[type=hidden]');
document.getElements('label input[type=radio] ! label').addEvent('click', function(){
    html.set('value', 'submitted with ' + this.getElement('input[type=radio]').get('checked'));
    this.getParent('form').submit();
});
```

in FF 23, it echoes back 'submitted with false'. Actually, same on Chrome 29.

The following change, adding a 10ms delay before submit, seems to allow the label click event to bubble to the input and set the value:

```
var html = document.getElement('input[type=hidden]');
document.getElements('label input[type=radio] ! label').addEvent('click', function(){
    // you can do this:
    // this.getElement('input[type=radio]').set('checked', true);
    html.set('value', 'submitted with ' + this.getElement('input[type=radio]').get('checked'));
    var f = this.getParent('form');
    f.submit.delay(10, f);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will probably go for this, the delay seems insignificant and it will hopefully make it work for all browsers presenting the same issue.

Comment: Per spec, the thing that triggers the label is its default activation behavior... which happens _after_ normal event handling.  So any delay at all, even 0, would work: it just needs to run async after the activation behavior has taken place.